# Movieclip moves together with player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, symbols

My problem is _saw in the flash I'm doing is just moving together with _player unlike _boundary(floor) is just static in the stage

```
public class PiggyRun extends MovieClip
{


private var _vy:Number;
private var _vx:Number;
```

my player in the script

```
public var _player:player;
public var _boundary:Boundary;
public var _rp:RG;
```

I declared saw just as the same with boundary

```
public var _saw:saw;
public var _jump:Boolean=true;



    public function PiggyRun():void
    {
    _rp.visible=false;
    _vx=0;
    _vy=0;
    _player.gotoAndStop('walking');
    stage.focus= stage;
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kDHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, kUHandler);


    }

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
```

I increased x because it's a running game

```
        _vy+=2;
        _vx+=.5;

        if(_vx>10)
        {
            _vx=10
        }
        _player.x+=_vx;
        _player.y+=_vy;




        borders();
        stageFocus();
        sawblade();
        }
```

The controls when pressed down

```
        private function kDHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {

            switch(e.keyCode)
            {

                case 38:
                if(_jump){
                _jump=false;    
                _vy=-20;

                }
                break;


                default:



            }
        }
```

I deleted contents of this function

```
        private function kUHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch(e.keyCode)
            {


            }
        }

        private function borders():void
        {
            if(_vy > 0)
            {
                if (_player.y>stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    _player.x=_rp.x;
                    _player.y=_rp.y;
                    _boundary.x=0;
                    _boundary.y=0;
                    _saw.x=0;
                    _saw.y=0;
                    _vy=0;
                    _vx=0;

                }else{
                    var border:Boolean=false;

                    if(_boundary.hitTestPoint(_player.x,_player.y,true))
                    {
                    border=true;

                    }
                        if (border)
                        {
                            while(border)
                            {

                            _player.y-=0.05;

                            _jump=true;
                            border=false;
                                if(_boundary.hitTestPoint(_player.x,_player.y,true))
                                {
                                border=true;

                                }
                            }
                            _vy=0;

                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

I put this function where in if the player hits the sawblade it will respawn back to the location of _rp but as I sad the 2 movieclips wont meet because they move simultaneously
even if I forcely put the _saw together with it the function doesn't work

```
        private function sawblade():void
        {
            if(_vy > 0)
            {
                if (_player.y>stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    _player.x=_rp.x;
                    _player.y=_rp.y;
                    _boundary.x=0;
                    _boundary.y=0;
                    _saw.x=0;
                    _saw.y=0;
                    _vy=0;
                    _vx=0;

                }else{
                    var sawn:Boolean=false;

                    if(_saw.hitTestPoint(_player.x,_player.y,true))
                    {
                    sawn=true;

                    }
                        if (sawn)
                        {
                            while(sawn)
                            {

                            _player.x=_rp.x;
                            _player.y=_rp.y;
                            _boundary.x=0;
                            _boundary.y=0;
                            _saw.x=0;
                            _saw.y=0;
                            _vy=0;
                            _vx=0;
                            _jump=true;
                            sawn=false;
                               if(_saw.hitTestPoint(_player.x,_player.y,true))
                            {
                                sawn=true;

                                }
                            }
                            _vy=0;

                        }
                }
            }
        }
        private function stageFocus():void
        {
            _boundary.x+=(stage.stageWidth * 0.5)-_player.x;
            _player.x=stage.stageWidth*0.5;
            _saw.x=5;
        }





}
```

Comment: Check if you addChild() your _saw object to the _player object. It seems that _saw.parent equals to _player, this makes it move with the player.

Comment: It's a bit hard to read your code like this. Try to clearly ask your question at the top. And then have one solid block of code (with additional comments instead of linebreaks). And like @Vesper I'm also interested in where you instantiate `Player` and `Saw` and how you add them to the stage.

Comment: I dont have any addChild, its a very basic flash game, I added saw and player by just drawing them into stage and making them symbols

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload the source file somewhere? I think it'll make a bit more sense for us.

Comment: here you go, it's the .fla and .as file of what I am creating
http://www.mediafire.com/?f98tava91i8cw5b

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't open the .fla (I have CS4)

Comment: here's a cs4 version http://www.mediafire.com/?8661rcvr2vdntmi I hope you can help me. I am having troubles in flash as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your fla and you didn't anything weird with the positioning of your MovieClips. The problem lies in your `stageFocus` function. You're constantly positioning the  position of your saw at x=5 and your player at the center of your stage. Only the `_boundary` is moved. So you should move your `_saw` like you're moving `_boundary`.

```
private function stageFocus():void
{
    var playerOffset:int = (stage.stageWidth * 0.5)-_player.x;

    _boundary.x+= playerOffset;
    _player.x=stage.stageWidth*0.5;
    _saw.x+=playerOffset;
}
```

And on a more general note, I think you're in a bit over your head here. Try narrowing down your game concept or maybe even [use a framework](http://flashpunk.net/learn/) to get you started.